# Matplotlib plt.show() method does not pop out the window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some problem with matplotlib's plt.show() method. When I run the following code, the plot is displayed inside IPython console. I am using Anaconda with Python 3.5

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open(r"F:\my_dir\example.txt", 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))

plt.plot(x,y, label = 'Loaded from file')

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("This is my plot")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

example.txt is as follows.

```
1,3
2,6
3,1
4,8
5,9
6,2
7,9
8,5
9,4
10,17
```

I am also pasting the `matplotlibrc` file content [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/3496QR3U8LgYfFXgzPpNMU8)

The `plt.get_backend()` command on the console gives

> 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'

I want the script to pop out the plot window. This used to happen earlier but now it has stopped. Please help

Comment: Try updating IPython and matplotlib

Comment: I installed Anaconda just over 2 weeks ago. And plt.show() used to get me pop out window till yesterday. Only today this strange behavior has started

Comment: Does it even create the plot? Try to use "savefig" and see if it fails at generating the plot or at showing it.

Comment: Philip, It does show the plot inside IPython console. I want to have pop up window for the plot.

Comment: Found answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356269/plot-inline-or-a-separate-window-using-matplotlib-in-spyder-ide). type `%matplotlib qt` when you want graphs in a separate window and `%matplotlib inline` when you want an inline plot

Comment: What os are you using? I know there are problems with matplotlib in the latest anaconda release on ubuntu.

Comment: I am on Windows 8.1 and installed Anaconda 64 bit Python 3.5

Comment: The IPython console can't display plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spyder, click Tools, Preferences, Ipython Console, Graphics. Under Graphics, change Backend to “automatic” instead of “inline”.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks pyan. This really helps.

But in addition, after following the above step, please restart your kernel to see the effect. Shortcut is "Ctrl+."

Comment: Hi Nishant Kumar. If someone's answer is helpfull to you, you can mark his answer as helpfull, for further users looking for similar questions. This helpfull flag is green checkbox near answer vote.