# Python Spyder choose where and when to show plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, spyder

I'm using Spyder3.1.2 IDE with Python 3.5 in Windows 10 and would like to know how to choose whether to show my plots in the iPython console or in a separate window. I found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356269/plot-inline-or-a-separate-window-using-matplotlib-in-spyder-ide) but I get an error when I type `%matplotlib qt` (No module named PyQt4). I have also changed the preferences to show graphics "automatically" instead of "inline", but I'm still getting them inline.

What I want to end up with is a `for` loop where on every iteration I add a new point to my graph, which is visible immediately and is shown in a separate window to the console.

Many thanks for your time

Comment: Edited the question to take into account your comments

Comment: What happens if instead of `%matplotlib qt` you use `%matplotlib qt5`?

Answer (score 1):

You can run your script in a new python console every time you run it.
For that press F6 or go to Run/Configure... and select "Execute in a new dedicated Python console.

[image]

Since this python console will not be an IPython console, there is no need to perform any other settings.
The plot should show up in a window upon `plt.show()`.