# Interactive Slider Bar Chart Color Control

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-interactive

I have four sets of random normal distributed numbers. The means are used to plot bar chart with each set's 95% confidence intervals plotted with errorbar.

Given a value y, four different colors will be set to the bars corresponding to the four ranges y is in:
1. lower bound to avg; 2. avg to upper bound; 3. below lower; 4. above upper.

I want to use a slider to control the y value and update the bar color each time I slide, I tried to use the following code but the bar charts cannot be plotted every update.

Could someone give me some ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(33500,150000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(41000,90000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(41000,120000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,55000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])

N = len(df.columns)-1  # Degree of Freedom
avg = df.mean(axis=1)  # Mean for each row
std = df.sem(axis=1)  # Unbiased Standard Deviation

year = df.index.map(str)  # Convert to String
conf95 = st.t.ppf(0.95, N)*std  # 95% Confidence Interval

upper = avg + conf95
lower = avg - conf95
colormap = ['blue', 'aqua', 'orange', 'brown']

ini = 39900
chk1 = ini>upper  # Check if y is greater than upper bound: blue
chk2 = ini<lower  # CHeck if y is smaller than lower bound: brown
chk3 = (ini>=lower) & (ini<=avg) # Check if y is in between avg and lower: orange
chk4 = (ini>avg) & (ini<=upper) # Check if y is in between avg and upper: aqua


fig, ax =plt.subplots()   
ax.bar(df.index[chk1.values], avg.iloc[chk1.values], width=1, edgecolor='k', color='blue')
ax.bar(df.index[chk2.values], avg.iloc[chk2.values], width=1, edgecolor='k', color='brown')
ax.bar(df.index[chk3.values], avg.iloc[chk3.values], width=1, edgecolor='k', color='orange')
ax.bar(df.index[chk4.values], avg.iloc[chk4.values], width=1, edgecolor='k', color='aqua')
ax.axhline(y=ini,xmin=0,xmax=10,linewidth=1,color='k')

ax.errorbar(df.index, avg, yerr=conf95, fmt='.',capsize=15, color='k')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.2)
plt.xticks(df.index, year)  # Map xlabel with String
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,max(avg)+1,max(avg)/5))

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axy = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

sy = Slider(axy, 'y', 0.1, int(max(upper)+1), valinit=ini)
```

Until this step the color works fine. Then the update func does not work thou.

```
def update(val):
    ax.cla()
    yy = sy.val    
    chk1 = yy>upper
    chk2 = yy<lower
    chk3 = (yy>=lower) & (yy<=avg)
    chk4 = (yy>avg) & (yy<=upper)
    ax.bar(df.index[chk1.values], avg.iloc[chk1.values], width=1, edgecolor='k', color='blue')
    ax.bar(df.index[chk2.values], avg.iloc[chk2.values], width=1, edgecolor='k', color='brown')
    ax.bar(df.index[chk3.values], avg.iloc[chk3.values], width=1, edgecolor='k', color='orange')
    ax.bar(df.index[chk4.values], avg.iloc[chk4.values], width=1, edgecolor='k', color='aqua')
    ax.bar(df.index, avg, width=1, edgecolor='k', color='silver')
    ax.errorbar(df.index, avg, yerr=conf95, fmt='.',capsize=15, color='k')
    ax.axhline(y=yy,xmin=0,xmax=10,linewidth=1,color='k')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

sy.on_changed(update)
```

Really appreciate any insights and Thank you guys very much!

Best
Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply delete the line

```
ax.bar(df.index, avg, width=1, edgecolor='k', color='silver')
```

I don't know why you put it there, but it will plot a complete unicolor barchart on top of the colored bars and hide them.

---

In order to make some interaction possible, an interactive backend needs to be used. So it will not work out of the box in IPython when `%matplotlib inline` mode is set. Options you have:

- Using `%matplotlib notebook` in IPython Qt console or jupyter notebook.
- Using a GUI backend when running code as a script, by adding `plt.show()`. In Spyder that can be ensured by running the script in a new dedicated window as [sketched here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656115/4124317).

Comment: Sorry that line was a left over from previous trial.

Comment: But when I delete this line, whenever I slide the slider, the bars still disappear. Could you give me a little more hint on your method?

Comment: If I plot the unicolor barchart on the top of the previous one, how to have the color be updated per the new yy value from the slider event>.<

Comment: The bars should not disappear when deleting this one line. When I simply copy the code from the question and delete that line, it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you! I used Pycharm and Spyder with IPython, in Pycharm the interactive was not active, while in Spyder that Bar disappearing problem persists... Then I run the code in Jupyter Notebook with Python 3 kernel the code works fine with %matplotlib notebook mode. Really appreciate your help!