# plt.show() not working in spyder 3.7(Anaconda 3)

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and Spyder. I am using Python 3.7 (Anaconda 3). I cannot get my graph after labelling `x` & `y` axis using `plt.show()` & also `plt.draw()` does not work either.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time=[1,2,4]
data_list_Ch4=[1,3,5]
plt.plot(time, data_list_Ch4)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Channel")
plt.show()
```

[screen shot of Spyder ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRHtC.png)

Comment: Did you try `plt.draw()` instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680211/plt-show-not-working-in-spyder-ide

Comment: I cannot recreate this, it works fine for me, at least with `time=[1,2,4]` and `data_list_Ch4=[1,3,5]`. Perhaps your data is messed up?

Comment: @Arnaud : also plt.draw() does not work either

Comment: @GarethMa: find below code for your reference. its still not working for simple code. Find attached screenshot above. 
`import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time=[1,2,4]
data_list_Ch4=[1,3,5]
plt.plot(time, data_list_Ch4)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Channel")
plt.show()`