# Why Python starts a new plot after every command?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spyder

I've been running the following lines of code and instead of adding labels and stuff to one plot, Python just creates a new plot after every command.

```
plt.plot(x, ydata, 'bo')
plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.ylabel('Dependent Variable')
plt.xlabel('Indepdendent Variable')
plt.show()
```

So, for example, after running the `plt.ylabel()` command, Python creates a new blank plot with just the y axis labeled as `'Dependent Variable'`.

**EDIT**
I've managed to solve the issue by following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680211/plt-show-not-working-in-spyder-ide)

Comment: You need to provide more information. What environment are you running the code in? What backend are you using?

Comment: anaconda3, the IDE I'm using is Spyder 5.0.5, and 'module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline'

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [*object oriented*](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) approach:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, ydata, 'bo')
ax.plot(x,y,'r')
ax.set_ylabel('Dependent Variable')
ax.set_xlabel('Indepdendent Variable')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried this and the output is a blank plot.

Answer (score 0):

You are making two plots here, so show them separately

```
plt.plot(x, ydata, 'bo') #first plot
plt.show() #show the first plot


plt.plot(x, y,'r') #second plot
plt.ylabel('Dependent Variable') #second custom ylabel
plt.xlabel('Indepdendent Variable') #second custom xlabel
plt.show() #show the second plot
```

If you want overlaying the plots:

```
plt.plot(x, ydata, label='bo')
plt.plot(x, y, label='r')
plt.ylabel('Dependent Variable')
plt.xlabel('Indepdendent Variable')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'd like them to appear on the same graph. But anyway it doesn't really solve the issue. Even if I plot them separately, it still creates a new plot after every single line of code.

Comment: @Anshez then it is something wrong with your environment try adding `%matplotlib inline` at the first line of your cell. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline

Comment: It doesn't work either. Also, it seems my backend is already set to 'module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline'. I am using Spyder IDE btw.