# python - plotly show command doesn't displays figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know this question have been asked here several times in the past..
BUT, I'm tried all the suggested solutions (regarding backend etc..) and no solution have solved my problem!!

I'm using Spyder and Jupyter and with both options it doesn't work and figure not displayed.

Can anyone help me solve this issue and understand what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: can you share what you have tried.. or sample code @erez

Comment: Hi Roshan, thanks for your response.
I tried to change the backed using python commands and by changing the matplotlib src file, also tried to update matplotlib and ipykernel versions.

This is my simplest code I run:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
plt.show()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot inline or a separate window using Matplotlib in Spyder IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356269/plot-inline-or-a-separate-window-using-matplotlib-in-spyder-ide)

Comment: @DavidG, Thanks!
You indeed right, it's the same issue and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Install matplotlib correctly.I ran this code on python shell and its working fine

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

or probably this [will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline) solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself well.
I see the figure as you see but I want to get it in a new and different window, not inside the console