# How do i plot a graph using a 2D List?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, matplotlib

I can't seem to figure out how to plot a graph as i always get an error message of "no numeric data to plot". I have also tried using a csv file to plot but it has not been successful.

This is my 2d list;

```
listofstock.append([1,"Microsoft","Mega",100,188,207])
listofstock.append([2,"Amazon","Mega",5,1700,3003])
listofstock.append([3,"PayPal","Large",80,100,188])
listofstock.append([4,"Apple","Large",100,60,110])
listofstock.append([5,"Fastly","Mid",30,40,76])
listofstock.append([6,"Square","Mid",30,40,178])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
import pandas as pd

listofstock = []
listofstock.append([1,"Microsoft","Mega",100,188,207])
listofstock.append([2,"Amazon","Mega",5,1700,3003])
listofstock.append([3,"PayPal","Large",80,100,188])
listofstock.append([4,"Apple","Large",100,60,110])
listofstock.append([5,"Fastly","Mid",30,40,76])
listofstock.append([6,"Square","Mid",30,40,178])

# if you are in a ipython-notebook
pd.DataFrame.from_records(listofstock).drop(0, axis=1).set_index([1]).plot()

# if you want to save the figure to a file
fig = pd.DataFrame.from_records(listofstock).drop(0, axis=1).set_index([1]).plot().get_figure()
fig.savefig('test.png')

# if you want to open in a new window
fig.show()
```

[image: chart]

Comment: the code seems to work but the graph doesn't seem to pop out.

Comment: I don't understand? What do you mean by pop out?

Comment: when i run it in visual studio, the graph doesn't come out.

Comment: You need to look into how to save your graph or open in a new window. There are many ways. The one I shared would work in a  iPython Notebook like Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @hannah I have edited my answer for various other scenarios. You can get more info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356269/plot-inline-or-a-separate-window-using-matplotlib-in-spyder-ide)

Comment: oh i see okay i understand now, thank you!