# Spyder + Matplotlib plots: combined functionality of qt5 and plots tab

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, qt5, spyder

I'm on Spyder 5.4.1.

I'm trying to find a way to combine the qt5 plot functionality (panning and zooming most of all) with the clean organization and ease of access from the 'inline' plots tab.

f.e. a way to open 'qt5 windows' from the plots tab

Anyone know of a way to combine the best of both worlds? :D

I'm not sure if it's possible but so far I've found following partial solutions:

1. Switch backend preferences from inline to qt5 or automatic

-> this has the disadvantage of opening all plots in a separate window, which is kind of messy.

2. Manually undocking from the plots tab

-> Doesn't have pan/zoom functionality of qt5 windows

3. 'Setting' backend to either inline or qt5, within the Python code, thanks to Robert Pollak:
   From: [Plot inline or a separate window using Matplotlib in Spyder IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356269/plot-inline-or-a-separate-window-using-matplotlib-in-spyder-ide)

"I have set the IPython console backend set to Automatic in the Spyder preferences.

In my scripts, I can now use switch_backend as either plt.switch_backend('module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline') or plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg') before each new plot, to make it either inline or separate/interactive."

-> This is currently my 'best' solution, it lets me anticipate which plots I'd like the functionality for, but of course it's not a very interactive way of doing things.